# Sending Multiple Intents from a Single Activity to Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

I am very new to android, and I am trying to send user-inputted data (their names) to another activity. I have in the past been able to send single lines between activities using Intents, but I have not been able to work out how to send two different strings to two different TextViews.

Here is my code for the MainActivity so far:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendNames();
            sendNames2();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void sendNames() {
    //sends player1's name to mainGame
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainGame.class);
    EditText player1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    String message = player1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}//sends player2's name to mainGame
 public void sendNames2(){
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainGame.class);
    EditText player2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    String message2 = player2.getText().toString();
    intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message2);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
}
```

Code for my second activity, MainGame:

```
package com.example.game;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainGame extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("NewAPI")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    //retrives player1's name
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    name1.setText(message);
    //retrivews player2's name
    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String message2 = intent2.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    name2.setText(message2);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

When I run this, I get whatever has been put in for 'name2' in both TextViews. What do I need to do to change this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you collect all of it and pass it in one bundle to the new activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when i run this i get whatever has been put in for 'name2' in both TextView's

This is because you are creating a new instance of the `Activity` with the second `Intent`. There are different ways you could do it. One would be create a single `Intent` as a member variable, instantiate it in your first function call, add extras, then add the other extra in the second method, and call `startActivity` there.

But it would probably be easier and more readable to just do it all at the same time.

```
 public void sendNames() {
    //sends player1's name to mainGame
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainGame.class);
    EditText player1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    String player1Name= player1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("player1Name", player1Name);
    EditText player2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    String player2Name= player2.getText().toString();
    intent2.putExtra("player2Name", player2Name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And just call this one method.

Then get it with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name1 = intent.getStringExtra("player1Name");
TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
name1.setText(message);

String name1 = intent2.getStringExtra("player2Name");
TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
name2.setText(name1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

An Intent is like a Map where you can store String (and other serializable objects) with a key. In your code you are using the same key `EXTRA_MESSAGE` twice.

Also, keep in mind that you use one Intent to start one Activity: you CANNOT have 2 Intent starting a single instance of an Activity. The solution is to put the 2 values with 2 distinct keys in one Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple paramters to an activity using intent, You don't have to create two different intent for doing this.

You can do this as follows

```
public void sendNames() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainGame.class);
    EditText player1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1);
    EditText player2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    String message = player1.getText().toString();
    String message2 = player2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and then get those values like

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String message2 = intent2.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name1);
name1.setText(message);
TextView name2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name2);
name2.setText(message2);
```