# Multiple Intents in a Single Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

Having issues with sending multiple pieces of data (in this case, three arrays(two int, one string)) over to a second activity page.

I am unsure of how this is done. What I would like to know is how to send these arrays in one Start Activity method, if that is possible. My current code is:

```
public void onClickGoToTeamSummary(View view)
{
    Intent intentTeamNames = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
    Intent intentTeamPoints = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
    Intent intentTeamGoals = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);

    intentTeamNames.putExtra("footballClubs", myTeams);
    intentTeamPoints.putExtra("clubPoints", pointsAttained);
    intentTeamGoals.putExtra("clubGoals", goalsScored);

    startActivity(intentTeamPoints);
    startActivity(intentTeamNames);
    startActivity(intentTeamGoals);
}
```

I had tried:

```
startActivity(intentTeamPoints, intentTeamNames, intentTeamGoals);
```

to no avail. To help, my getIntent in the next activity looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    Intent intentClubNames = getIntent();
    String[] club_names = intentClubNames.getStringArrayExtra("footballClubs");

    Intent intentClubPoints = getIntent();
    int[] team_points = intentClubPoints.getIntArrayExtra("clubPoints");

    Intent intentTeamGoals = getIntent();
    int[] club_goals = intentTeamGoals.getIntArrayExtra("clubGoals");
}
```

The code itself works provided only one startActivity is used. I would like to know how to pass all my arrays into the second activity page through one activity if anyone can help me.

Comment: I think this one is explained here clearly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195734/sending-multiple-intents-from-a-single-activity-to-another-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

You can send all values in single `Intent`

```
public void onClickGoToTeamSummary(View view)
{
    Intent intentTeamNames = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);

    intentTeamNames.putExtra("footballClubs", myTeams);
    intentTeamNames.putExtra("clubPoints", pointsAttained);
    intentTeamNames.putExtra("clubGoals", goalsScored);

    startActivity(intentTeamNames);
}
```

and

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    Intent intentClubNames = getIntent();
    String[] club_names = intentClubNames.getStringArrayExtra("footballClubs");
    int[] team_points = intentClubNames.getIntArrayExtra("clubPoints");
    int[] club_goals = intentClubNames.getIntArrayExtra("clubGoals");
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Did not realize you could put more than one value into a single Intent. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use multiple `Intents` but multiple extras.

```
// create your Intent as normal
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);

// then you can add multiple extras
myIntent.putExtra("footballClubs", myTeams);
myIntent.putExtra("clubPoints", pointsAttained);
myIntent.putExtra("clubGoals", goalsScored);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then receiving them would be the same. You would just receive the one `Intent` and use the key as normal for each extra `Array`.