# Pass multiple Intents to multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass info as shown in this picture [screen description](http://postimg.org/image/3nowmom6z/)

I know that my code is working, becuase with one `Intent` it works perfectley. However, when I try to put two or more `Intent`s it seems to get messed up. I also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195734/sending-multiple-intents-from-a-single-activity-to-another-activity) to find a sutibale solution, but I don't think I can use it the same way. Thanks in advance

--update--

still dosen't work

i did this on my saving side

```
 Intent saveIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);             
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("time", displayTime.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(saveIntent);
```

and this on my reciving side

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String time = preferences.getString("time",null);
        if (time != null)
           getTime.setText(time);
```

- Main Activity:

  ```
  private Button createNewEvent;
  private Button showMyEvents;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  createNewEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateNewEvent);
  showMyEvents = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShowMyEvents);
   }

  public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.bCreateNewEvent:
              Intent createNewEventIntent = new Intent(this,     CreateNewEventActivity.class);
              startActivity(createNewEventIntent);


              break;
          case R.id.bShowMyEvents:
              Intent myEventsIntent = new Intent(this,MyEventsActivity.class); 
            startActivity(myEventsIntent);

            break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- screen 1 save button:

  ```
         case R.id.bSaveNewEvent:
        Intent putIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyEventsActivity.class);
         // String  text = displayTime.getText().toString();
          putIntent.putExtra("time",displayTime.getText().toString());
          Intent saveIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(saveIntent);
          startActivity(putIntent);
  ```
- screen 2 getExtras

  ```
   public class MyEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView getTime;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_events);

  getTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetTime);
  Intent in = getIntent();
  String name = in.getStringExtra("time");
  getTime.setText(name);
     /* Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null){
      getTime.setText(extras.getString("time"));

  }*/
  ```

Comment: use sharedpreferences to store and get data

Comment: use local storage for save data...

Comment: What order of things causing something to get messed up, and what exactly is "messed up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save data that will be need to be used in multiple other activities, `SharedPreferences` will be the easiest solution.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

When you want to save a value, you would use:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("time", displayTime.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Then when you want to get the preference later on you would use:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String time = preferences.getString("time", "");
```

Comment: hi , do i need to declare MY_PREFS_NAME on all activities?

Comment: No, you would only use that when you are setting or getting stored values.

Comment: yes but i declared that on screen 1 there i save my values, now i also need to declare it on screen 2 when i get my values?

Comment: Ok, so if you are saving the values in your first activity, you will need to have your variable `MY_PREFS_NAME` there. Also, any other activities that need to get those saved values later will also need that same variable to open the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: okay i did what you said, and declared public static ' final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile" '; on both files, not now im getting null pointer on  getTime.setText(time); [getTime is a TextView]. on the debug i can see the time passed

Comment: Sounds like your textview is null. That is a different issue

Comment: nevermind,im an idiot i forgot initialize getTime, thank!